# CKEDITOR On Enter Do <br> But keep on one line

Tags: php, javascript, ckeditor

Currently in CKEDITOR when I type
"Hello

World!"

The source is

```
<p>Hello</p>

<p>&nbsp;</p>

<p>World!</p>

<p>&nbsp;</p>
```

I've looked almost everywhere and what I'd like is

"Hello

World!"

to render

```
<p>Hello<br>World!</p>
```

or

```
<p>Hello</p><br><p>World!</p>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The shift + enter key is indeed what your looking for like chrisLTD suggested. 
But if you like to configure it.

Here you can find a explanation of the enter key configurations and how to configure. 
http://ckeditor.com/ckeditor_4.1rc/samples/plugins/enterkey/enterkey.html

```
CKEDITOR.replace( 'textarea_id', {
enterMode: CKEDITOR.ENTER_BR
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try holding down shift while pressing enter.

[More info on the CKEditor forum's here.](http://ckeditor.com/forums/Support/Line-Breaks)